# Firebase signInWithCustomToken handle token expiry

Tags: firebase

I'm using firebase 9.x with custom authentication. According to the documentation the token expiry cannot be more than one hour. Is there a listener which I can register to that will be called when the token expires.

The documentation also talks about automatic refreshing of tokens. I believe that is not applicable for custom authentication. Let me know otherwise.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server#use_the_firebase_server_sdk

Ideally the documentation (above) should have the requested information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The token that is generated server side (custom auth) is a JWT (JSON Web Token). This token must be supplied by your client (Android?) to the Firebase server to authenticate the user to Firebase. In the 9.x libraries, it seems these tokens now have a maximum life of an hour (i.e they are no longer accepted after 60 mins). (See Sam Stern's comment in this issue: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/31).

Sam indicates that once authentication has occurred using a custom generated token, the Android client will remain authorised until signed out.

If you actually require to know when your JWT token is valid until, it should be 60 minutes after you generate it on your server. If the token has not yet been used for auth with Firebase, at this point you could regenerate a new one and use that instead.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is misleading. It should say you have 1 hour to use the custom token to sign in. I also feel if the token is that temporary, then it should be single use. Otherwise it is confusing how they want you to use the token.

The SDK will take care of keeping the sessions tokens up to date IF YOU ARE SETUP correctly. For more info The custom tokens are only used to start a SESSION. So you have to have hour to use a custom token to SIGN IN. Once you are signed in and your Firebase Admin account and app configuration is setup correctly, the SDK can communicate back and forth with the Firebase back-end to keep the tokens up to date. Once you sign out with FirebaseAuth.signout(), you will need a new custom token to sign back in if it has been over 1 hour.

So in most cases, you really do not need to listen for token expiration

Answer (score 1):

have you tried AuthListener?

`mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            user.getCurrentUser().getToken(true);
            // ...
        }
    };;
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);`